# Помогите пожалуйста с поиском в матрице на python

Tags: python, строки, матрицы, поиск

Поиск из массива
Вам дана матрица n * m, проверьте, что эта матрица содержит s строк слов, образованных путем объединения последовательных букв по оси x или оси y.

Входные данные:
В первой строке n и m(1≤n,m≤100)) вводятся натуральные числа.
В следующих n строках вводятся m букв, разделенных пробелами. В следующей строке записано количество тестов k ( 1001≤k≤100). Для каждого теста вводится отдельная строка.

Выходные данные:
Для каждого теста выведите «да», если это слово можно найти в матрице, иначе «нет» (в отдельных строках). Проверить можно только по вертикали и горизонтали по прямой.

```
Примеры
#   ввод.txt    вывод.txt
1               да 
5 6             нет 
absdef          нет 
pruhpg          да  
pliyqt          да
lkgrfk 
epqtgo 
5 
apple 
bar 
ari 
def 
el
```

Comment: Так, и в чём сложность? Перебираете, проверяете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

берете очередное слово (подстроку),
сначала в каждой строке матрицы ищите подстроку и так для каждого слова. Потом транспонируете матрицу и выполните то же самое(теперь вы фактически ищите в столбцах).
Это самый быстрый способ, с точки зрения реализации, на моей взгляд.

Также вам следует уточнить, считается ли слово найденным, если оно записано справа налево